# Cards not spaced in Android 5.0, as they are in pre-lollipop

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using CardView as rows in a listview. The cards in Android 4.0 -4.4 are well spaced, just as desired, but in Andorid 5.0, they aren't.

Here are the screenshots:

For Android 5.0:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSbjl.png

for pre-lollipop, and the way I want it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qLhY.jpg

Here's the code for the CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:stateListAnimator="@anim/anim"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                cardview:cardElevation="5dp"
                                cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
                                cardview:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:longClickable="true"
                                android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">
```

Here's the code for the listview these cards are a part of:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

What is it that's causing the cards to not be spaced on Android 5.0? I hope I've provided the information needed.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't upload the images in the description. Apparently my reputation needs to be a minimum of 10 to be able to do that.

Comment: Try to add a margin to the top and bottom of your CardView, or add a divider and dividerHeight to your ListView.

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel There is a default divider in the listView, which I was planning to remove, since it doesn't look very nice. So I do not want dividers. Also, adding a margin didn't help.

Comment: The divider can also be transparant. That way it can be used as spacing between the items.

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel no luck. It still looks the same.

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel, thank you for helping out. I solved the issue. I've answered, if you'd like to check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I solved the issue by adding :

```
cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

You can read about it here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding

Comment: cool! I struggled with my padding having no effets on my card.